# Toggle conditions Angularjs with <a> tag

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working on a code, where in i have icons under an < a > tag. Originally, I had a dropdown so showing a div on that was easy since a dropdown has a value but how do i code the same thing under an < a > tag?

Comment: Can you explain what you want more clearly?Also share what have you tried so far or a plunkr demo.Help us to help you :)

Comment: Please write you code that what you trying to do.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/0gOuf8D3BKb2lHP5ObX9?p=preview
This is just an example i want to toggle X Y and Z div based on value and also send the value in the json call

Comment: Based on what condition you want to toggle? Suppose if I press X what should happen?

Comment: if i click X, the div with x should be displayed, that i can do with ng-if, but i want to assign a VALUE to the < a > tag how do i do it?

Comment: @MissDoubtfire: from my answer can you show me where you need to assign the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <div>
        <a href="#" ng-click="assignVal('X')">X</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="assignVal('Y')">Y</a>
        <a href="#" ng-click="assignVal('Z')">Z</a>         
</div>

        <div ng-if="showX">X --> div</div>
        <div ng-if="showY">Y --> div</div>
        <div ng-if="showZ">Z --> div</div>

  </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
 var appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);

    appModule.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.assignVal = function(val) {          
            if (val === 'X') {
                $scope.showX = true;
                $scope.showY = false;
                $scope.showZ = false;
            } else if (val === 'Y') {
                $scope.showX = false;
                $scope.showY = true;
                $scope.showZ = false;
            } else if (val === 'Z'){
                $scope.showX = false;
                $scope.showY = false;
                $scope.showZ = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a value to a variable when `<a>` is clicked, use `ng-click`, not `ng-model`.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="showX = !showX">X</a>
<div ng-if="showX">X</div>
```

Comment: @PratapA.K I updated my answer and `ng-click` is toggling now.

Comment: @PratapA.K Btw. question says "Toggle", but [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053267/toggle-conditions-angularjs-with-a-tag/35054300#comment57831842_35053267) says "Assign"

Comment: If you click on x, div x should display and y and z should hide

Comment: @PratapA.K And which part of question or comments says that?

Comment: see 5th comment from @Miss Doubtfire,

Comment: @PratapA.K OK, you're right. But it's not that obvious. However I'll leave my answer because it's different than your.